# Converting columns to rows with joined tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, grouping, rows, transpose

I have the following structure:

```
WordTemplatesByAssemblyPackage
[PackageId] [TemplateId]

WordTemplate
[TemplateId] [Name]

WordTemplatePlainDataMappings
[TemplateId] [UDF01SdtTag] [UDF02SdtTag] [UDF03SdtTag] ... [UDF20SdtTag]

WordTemplateTableDataMappings
[TemplateId] [TableContainerSdtTag] [Col01SdtTag] [Col02SdtTag] ... [Col10SdtTag]
```

I've been trying hard to convert the following query but instead of selecting the columns I want to convert them to rows

```
SELECT
t.Name,
pd.UDF01SdtTag,
pd.UDF02SdtTag,
pd.UDF03SdtTag,
tpd.TableContainerSdtTag,
tpd.Col01SdtTag,
tpd.Col02SdtTag,
tpd.Col03SdtTag

FROM
doc.WordTemplatesByAssemblyPackage AS p
INNER JOIN doc.WordTemplate AS t ON p.TemplateId = t.TemplateId AND p.TemplateId = t.TemplateId
LEFT JOIN doc.WordTemplatePlainDataMappings AS pd ON pd.TemplateId = t.TemplateId AND pd.TemplateId = t.TemplateId
LEFT JOIN doc.WordTemplateTableDataMappings AS tpd ON tpd.TemplateId = t.TemplateId AND tpd.TemplateId = t.TemplateId
WHERE
p.PackageId = 3
```

I've been trying with unpiv but all I get is

```
42000 - [SQL Server]The column 'TemplateId' was specified multiple times for 'unpiv'.
42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "p.TemplateId" could not be bound.
```

Finally, the result I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
t.Name        Field                 Value

Template 1    Field 1               Value
Template 1    Field 2               Value
Template 1    Table 1 - Field 1     Value
Template 2    Field 1               Value
Template 2    Table 1 Field 1       Value
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for UNPIVOT operator

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396